# Keep both pendingIntents with the same requestCode

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am developing an alarm application in Android. The flow is really simple, Im just creating a **PendingIntent** and then I call the **setExact()** method in the **AlarmManager** much like below.

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BroadcastReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
        System.currentTimeMillis() + difference, pendingIntent);
```

After some tests I realized that with the above snippet I can set only one alarm because I set the **requestCode** of the **pendingIntent** to zero, and if I set another alarm with the **requestCode** set to 0 then it will overwrite the previous one. Is there a way to fix this without changing the **requestCode**? I was thinking maybe the flags can help me but I didn't find a flag that doesn't overwrite the previous pendingIntent.

I know that the obvious solution is to change 0 to another int and then keep track of all my ints, picking one that is not used. That solution would be fine if I was just starting the project, however I am already in the middle and I use as request codes predefined **Enums**. It is very difficult to change this mechanic and keep track of individual ints thats why I am asking if there is a way of not overwriting a pendingIntent when a new one with the same **requestCode** is registered. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am asking if there exists a certain type of flag that will be able to differentiate them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am asking if there exists a certain type of flag that will be able to differentiate them

There is not, and it makes sense because this is already the purpose of the requestCode parameter.

For information, these are your options regarding flags:

[image]

You will have to change your mechanism to make it possible to have different requestCodes for Pending Intents. It may be a lot of work, but it is what you have to do.

Comment: Actually, no. You don't have to use different `requestCode`s if you make the `Intent`s all unique. You can do that by setting different ACTION or different DATA in each `Intent`.

Comment: @David excellent, I didn't know. If OP removes the accept I will delete my answer

Answer (score 4):

You can make the `Intent`s unique be setting a different ACTION on each one. Then you could still use the same `requestCode` and would have different `PendingIntent`s.

You'll need to keep track of the ACTIONs you use if you want to be able to cancel the alarms later.

Comment: Or you can use `setData` method. See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29)